# Put Selected Gridview Row Data to a Databound Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use this code to put the selected gridview row to Label or textbox and they are working properly, However when I choose to display the data in a dropdownlist which loads data from sqldatasource, it produces this error:

*'ddlRPGroup' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.*

```
protected void grdTenant_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = grdTenant.SelectedRow;
    lblRPCode.Text  = row.Cells[1].Text;
    lblRP.Text   = row.Cells[2].Text;
    lblType.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
    lblBusiness.Text  = row.Cells[4].Text;

    ddlRPGroup.SelectedValue = row.Cells[5].Text;
}
```

Markup

```
<table border="0" class="tblEditTenant"  cellpadding="3">
     <tr>
        <td colspan ="4" style="font-weight: 700; font-size: medium;"><asp:Label ID="lblRP" runat="server" Text="Retail Partner"></asp:Label>- 
        <asp:Label ID="lblRPCode" runat="server" Text="RP Code"></asp:Label>  </td>                         
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Type:</td>
          <td colspan ="3"><asp:Label ID="lblType" runat="server" Text="Type"></asp:Label></td>
       </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Business:</td>
          <td colspan ="3"><asp:Label ID="lblBusiness" runat="server" Text="Business"></asp:Label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>RP Group:</td>
          <td colspan ="3">
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRPGroup" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="name" DataValueField="code"></asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
               </asp:DropDownList>
          </td>                             
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Show your MarkUp code as well. Are you getting any exception? Are you sure your dropdown is populated before you are trying to set it's value?

Comment: What do you mean it fails? You get any exception or error message?

Comment: ok , I am editing my question

Comment: Your exception tells us that in your dropdown data there is now value you want to set it to

Answer (score 1):

What the error tells you, that the value you want to select in your DropdownList does not yet exist in the list.

If this value already should be in the ddl, then you need to edit the DataSource of your ddl to insert the correct values. 
If you want to insert the selected value into the dropdownlist first and then select it, do it like this:

```
protected void grdTenant_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = grdTenant.SelectedRow;
    lblRPCode.Text  = row.Cells[1].Text;
    lblRP.Text   = row.Cells[2].Text;
    lblType.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
    lblBusiness.Text  = row.Cells[4].Text;

    //new ListItem with Text and Value of cells[5] gets inserted into ddl
    ddlRPGroup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(row.Cells[5].Text,row.Cells[5].Text));
    ddlRPGroup.SelectedValue = row.Cells[5].Text;
}
```

If this value should already be in the list, the you need to edit your datasource to return to proper values.

Comment: Actually, I should not do an inserting in this. Column 5 in the gridview is about ITEM GROUPING which is based on the dropdownlist the first time it was added to the database. So whatever value that is in the gridview column or cell #5 , surely it is in the databound dropdown. Example: "NONE" this is included as item in the dropdownlist.

Comment: Then debug your list and check which value is behind the item with the Text "NONE". After this check which value cells[5].Text currently has. There has to be one list item with the `Value` of this Textproperty.

Comment: Thanks, your answer gives me the idea to know what causes the error and leads to it being answered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer already, and what is causing the error.

Just replace this line

```
ddlRPGroup.SelectedValue = row.Cells[5].Text;
```

with this:

```
ddlRPGroup.SelectedItem.Text = row.Cells[5].Text;
```

It should be selectItem.Text because selectedValue points the code of the item and not the item itself